# SQL count of hours by 2 tables in 1 query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables A and B. Table A has ID and type of ticket. Table B has The same ID and hours to ticket.

```
table A
-Id
-Type
```

```
table B
-SameID
-hours
```

I need to get hours by Type in one query without Declare.
Example:

```
Type1 : 12
Type2 : 32 
...
```

Comment: @YogeshSharma i don`t know which one. it`s on Trac system.

Comment: is ID unique in Table A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the sum of hours for each Type? If using MSSQL and hours is an expression of the exact numeric or approximate numeric data type category (except bit..) AND id is unique in table A:

```
select  SUM(hours)
FROM A 
left join B on A.Id = B.SameID
group by Type
```

If your just looking for the hours for each id, just do a simple join

Answer (score 0):

Try a JOIN along the lines of:

```
SELECT a.Type,b.Hours 
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
ON a.Id=b.Id
GROUP BY a.Id
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This will trigger that Type and Hours  are invalid in the select list because they are not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause